# iOS ARC @property and self

Tags: ios, properties, automatic-ref-counting

I just start my programming with ARC,
when I test the `weak`, `strong` `@property` with a  demo, I found a strange thing;
here is the code:

In .h file, I made a member variable `ctView` and add `@property` to manage getter and setter.

```
    @interface ViewController : UIViewController
    {
      CTView * ctView;
    }
    @property(nonatomic,strong)CTView * ctView;
```

Then in .m file, `viewdidload` method, I print the point address out.

```
ctView = [[CTView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,10,300,400)];    
NSLog(@"%p %p ",self.ctView,ctView);
```

Log:

```
0x0 0x7156530
```

Thank you guys, and I made a mistake that, the MRC code is on a LLVM GCC 4.2 compiler，and ARC code is Apple LLVM 4.1, this issue makes MRC app crashes, :)

Comment: @Puneeet The issue is that the property is returning a `nil` pointer, whereas the instance variable has been initialized.

Comment: I frankly don't understand the downvotes. It's a legitimate question from a person learning Objective-C and it's also clear and  well written.

Answer (score 2):

If you look closely you'll find a warning from the compiler saying:

> Autosynthesized property `ctView` will use synthesized variable `_ctView`, not existing variable `ctView`

That is pretty self-explanatory.

This happens because modern versions of the compiler will automatically synthesize variables when you declare a property. As a matter of fact skipping the `@synthesized` directive will cause the compiler to insert it for you in this form

```
@synthesize ctView = _ctView;
```

which automatically creates

- the instance variable `_ctView`
- the getter method `-ctView`
- the setter method `-setCtView:`

Declaring variables **and** the property is not needed anymore (unless you're supporting legacy code written in Objective-C 1.x), so you can just skip the variable declaration and the `@synthesize` directive altogether. If you really want to use your variable, you have to explicitly insert

```
@synthesize ctView; // in this case '= ctView' is implicit, so you can skip it
```

in your implementation file, but you will have no benefits and you will also break the naming convention for instance variables.

Comment: Gabriele In MRC I used to code like this, if the variable is not used or assigned by other class, I don't add property to avoid retain with self.tV = [[uiview alloc] init]; now it seems a bit mistake, and if using systhesis ctView, it will not create var _ctView, this works smoothly. many thanks , you save my day

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the issue. What do you want to avoid exactly?

Comment: @nickyu, you're welcome. Also remember that you can declare a property as `weak` if you don't want to retain on assignment. As a general tip, use properties whenever possible. I think it's being years since I declared my last variable ;)

Comment: @nickyu since you're new on SO, let me take this opportunity to remember you that it's a good practice to accept answers :)

Answer (score 1):

With the new Xcode you no longer have to declare the ivar, one is automatically create with the same name as the property but prefixed with an `_`.
So the ivar for your property `ctView` is called `_ctView`.

If you want to use your own ivar you will have to tell the compiler this:

```
@synthesize ctView = ctView;
```

Comment: I think `@synthesize ctView;` will suffice ;)

Comment: @GabrielePetronella your might right, but this way you know for sure.

Comment: Yeah, but it's useless (and not so pretty) code :) Just try and you'll see that `= ctView` is implicit.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't provide your own implementation of the property's getters and setters or if you simply @synthesize them without providing a variable name, Objective-C will automatically back your property by a variable with a name equal to _ + property name. So in your case, your `ctView` property is automatically backed by a variable named `_ctView`. The instance variable you've defined yourself is a **different** variable.

You can fix it in 3 ways:

1. Use only getters and setters to access your property, so use `self.ctView = [[CTView alloc] init...` instead of `ctView = ...` and remove your the variable that you defined yourself.
2. Access your instance variable using the correct name: `_ctView = ...`.
3. Let the compiler know which backing variable to use by using `@synthesize ctView = ctView;` in your .m file.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to `@synthesize` a property with a instance variable after Xcode4.4,it can be done automatically. But the automatically made ivar's name is the property's prefixed by a "_",so you `ctView` iVar and `self.ctView` is not the same except you add a manually `@sythesize ctView=ctView`;

Comment: same comment as above, `@synthesize ctView;` would suffice, as `= ctView` is implicit if you don't specify any name.

Answer (score -1):

`self.ctView`, which is an iVar named `_ctView`, never get alloc inited. 
Only `ctView` (note that != `_ctView`) was alloc inited.

That's why you don't get an address for `self.ctView` or `_ctView`.

Comment: -1 `self.ctView` is **not** an ivar named `_ctView`. `self.ctView` is a method call.

Comment: I found here a funny place. :)